# Does Morphline convertTimestamp command work for multiple fields in solr schema

Tags: hadoop, solr, mapreduce, cloudera, solrcloud

Hi I have multiple date fields in my solr schema and they are in different formats. I am using Morphlineindexertool to index data and load in solr.

I am not having any problems indexing one date field but if I try to index multiple date filed using convertTimestamp command in morphline conf I am not able to see data indexed. This is how I wrote my mrphline.conf for multiple timestamps.

```
{convertTimestamp {
field : timestamp1
inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
inputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
outputTimezone : UTC
}}

{convertTimestamp {
field : timestamp2
inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
inputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
outputTimezone : UTC
}}
```

Is this the right way to do it in morphlines? I can't see any examples online for multiple timestamps.

Comment: You can convert any number of fields using convertTimestamp function. If your input date is not in one of the input formats you have specified then it might not recognize the input and can't convert it to the required output format. Try giving like dis                                                {
  convertTimestamp {
   field : DATE
   inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
   inputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
   outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
   outputTimezone : UTC
}
}

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, My question is how can we convert multiple timestamp colums or fields.    {convertTimestamp {field : timestamp1
inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
inputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
outputTimezone : UTC
}{field : timestamp2
inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
inputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
outputTimezone : UTC
}} is this the right format or not?

Comment: That is right format